# Will the electrolyte surface become charged if one electrode is raised out of solution?

Tags: electrochemistry

What would the potential distribution be if I were to immerse a single inert (graphite) electrode in an aqueous solution with good ionic conductivity and hold it at a high (ca. $\pu{24V}$) potential vs. an electrode that would remain in the air above the solution's surface?

I don't expect anything to happen at the immersed electrode interface because the solution should remain equipotential.

But, what about the air-water interface? Would the electric field induce a surface charge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, what about the air-water interface? Would the electric field induce a surface charge?

**Yes.**  Basically, by locating one of your electrodes out of the solution, you've assembled an [air-gap capacitor](http://www.capacitorguide.com/tag/air-gap-capacitor/), though a fairly inefficient/low-quality one.

Per that above link, typical metal-plate "[a]ir capacitors have a small capacitance which usually lies between $\pu{100pF}$ and $\pu{1nF}$". High-level, the [definition of capacitance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance) is:

$$
C = {q\over V} \quad\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\quad q = CV
$$

Assuming that this water/electrode air capacitor has similar properties to the above-referenced metal-plate air-gap capacitor, the charge accumulated at the electrolyte surface under a $\pu{24V}$ applied potential should be between $2.4$ and $\pu{24nC}$. A similar amount of charge, but of opposite sign, should of course accumulate at the surface of the elevated electrode.

> I don't expect anything to happen at the immersed electrode interface because the solution should remain equipotential.

This will be true at steady-state, as the entirety of the potential drop is going to be supported by the air gap.

However, you *will* have some minuscule amount of *transient* electrochemical activity at your submerged electrode right when you turn on your power supply, as the system adjusts from the $\pu{0V}$ to the $\pu{24V}$ applied voltage.

Comment: Thank you! Seeing it as an air capacitor makes complete sense.